# Modify Graph Orientation in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I am trying to create a bar graph but have it horizontally oriented. So far I can only make it vertical with the following code. I have been digging
around and man sources only show the vertical orientation. Is there a 
way to

```
    Sub test_tic_count_graph()

    Dim chtTicCount As chart
    Dim ticCountGraph As Worksheet

    Set ticCountGraph = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ticCountGraph")
    Set chtTicCount = ticCountGraph.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered).chart

    With chtTicCount

                    .SetSourceData Source:=ticCountGraph.Range("A1:B9")


                    ''Activating the xlValue so we can refer to x-y values.
                    .HasAxis(xlValue, xlPrimary) = True
                    .HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary) = True

                    .Legend.Font.Size = 10
                    '' Sets legend position 100 points from top.
                    .Legend.Top = 100


                    ''Label the X - axis. Note it's xlCategory.
                    With .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
                        .HasTitle = True
                        .AxisTitle.Text = "DEVICE"
                        .AxisTitle.Font.Size = 10

                        '' Modify tickmark labels font size.
                        .TickLabels.Font.Size = 10

                    End With

                    '' Label the Y - axis. Note it's xlValue.
                    With .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
                        .HasTitle = True
                        ''.AxisTitle.Text = "CPU %"
                        .AxisTitle.Font.Size = 10
                        .TickLabels.Font.Size = 10
                        ''.MaximumScale = 1

                    End With

            End With

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xlColumnClustered` is the ChartType property value for vertical bars. You probably want `xlBarClustered` for horizontal bars.